# Image from gallery, photos and camera not working always

Tags: android, image

> ```
>   final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
>                 final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>                 final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
>                 final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
>                 for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
>                     final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
>                     final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
>                     intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
>                     intent.setPackage(packageName);
>                     cameraIntents.add(intent);
>                 }
>                 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
>                         MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);   galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
>                 final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
>                 chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
>                 startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);
> ```

So , thats How I call to open either camera or take a picture. How i read them on onactivityresult????check below the code. The problem, when image chosen from  photos it works, when taken from camera it works. But when chosen from gallery folder, it doesnt work for some reason. Also some of clients are reporting me problem on sony xperia e4 phones.

> ```
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>     try {
>         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1
>                 ) {
>             Bitmap bm = null;
>             try
>             {
>                 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
>                 bm = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
>             }
>             catch(Exception e)
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
>                     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>                     options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
>                     options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
>                     options.inDither = true;
>                     String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
>                     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
>                             selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
>                     cursor.moveToFirst();
>                     int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
>                     String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
>                     cursor.close();
>                     Common.setBitmap(null);
>                     bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);           
>    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Common.getRealPathFromURI(data.getData(), rootView.getContext()), bounds);
>                     if(bm == null)
>                         bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Common.getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage, AddStoreActivity.this), options);
>                     if(bm == null)
>                         bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
>                 }
>                 catch(Exception e1)
>                 {
>                 }
>             }        
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>     }
> }
>
>
>
>
>
>  public static String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI, Context cont) {
>     Cursor cursor = cont.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
>     if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
>         return contentURI.getPath();
>     } else {
>         cursor.moveToFirst();
>         int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA);
>         return cursor.getString(idx);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do this and it works:

```
private void displayAddPhotoDialog() {
        final CharSequence[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.photo_dialog_options);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.photo_dialog_title));
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == TAKE_PHOTO_OPTION) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                } else if (item == CHOOSE_FROM_LIBRARY_OPTION) {
                    dispatchPickImageIntent();
                } else if (item == CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


protected void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_camera_error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    protected void dispatchPickImageIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        } else {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        }
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_picture)), GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

And your onActivityResult method should look like this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            photoReceivedFromCamera = true;
            getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(imageUri);
            getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            //do want you want with the uri(taken photo)
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //The user cancelled the take picture action...
            if (!photoReceivedFromCamera) {
                //If the user has not previously taken a picture,
                //this means he is cancelling the take photo process
                onCancelTakePicture();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
           //do want you want with the uri(selected image)
        }
    }
```